# get city from geocoder results?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, street-address, city

Having problems getting the different arrays content from geocoder results.

item.formatted_address works but not item.address_components.locality?

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {

        response($.map(results, function(item) {

        alert(item.formatted_address+" "+item.address_components.locality)
    }            
});
```

// the array returned is;

```
 "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            } ],
          "formatted_address" : "Westminster, London, UK" // rest of array...
```

any help appreciated!

Dc

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Got this working in the end using:

```
var arrAddress = item.address_components;
var itemRoute='';
var itemLocality='';
var itemCountry='';
var itemPc='';
var itemSnumber='';

// iterate through address_component array
$.each(arrAddress, function (i, address_component) {
    console.log('address_component:'+i);

    if (address_component.types[0] == "route"){
        console.log(i+": route:"+address_component.long_name);
        itemRoute = address_component.long_name;
    }

    if (address_component.types[0] == "locality"){
        console.log("town:"+address_component.long_name);
        itemLocality = address_component.long_name;
    }

    if (address_component.types[0] == "country"){ 
        console.log("country:"+address_component.long_name); 
        itemCountry = address_component.long_name;
    }

    if (address_component.types[0] == "postal_code_prefix"){ 
        console.log("pc:"+address_component.long_name);  
        itemPc = address_component.long_name;
    }

    if (address_component.types[0] == "street_number"){ 
        console.log("street_number:"+address_component.long_name);  
        itemSnumber = address_component.long_name;
    }
    //return false; // break the loop   
});
```

Comment: Works nicely but would be more elegant and less code as a 'switch' statement.

Comment: Do not expect this to work reliable, Google's geocode is flawed in many ways.  "locality" is not always available, sometimes the city is actually in the state (level_1) field.  Especially when the return type is ROOFTOP the Google Geocode results are bad. In foreign countries they suddenly switch format. You can trust "APPROXIMATE" results a lot more than "ROOFTOP"

Comment: Correct. Doesn't work reliably. Google notes that there's no consistency in the components you get in your response. Also that it might change over time.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details under "Place Details Results"

Answer (score 15):

tried a couple of different requests:

[MK107BX](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=MK107BX,UK&sensor=false)

[Cleveland Park Crescent, UK](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2a%20Cleveland%20Park%20Crescent,UK&sensor=false)

like you say, array size returned is inconsistent but the Town for both results appears to be in the address_component item with type of [ "locality", "political" ]. Perhaps you could use that as an indicator?

**EDIT**: get the locality object using jQuery, add this to your *response* function:

```
var arrAddress = item.results[0].address_components;
// iterate through address_component array
$.each(arrAddress, function (i, address_component) {
    if (address_component.types[0] == "locality") // locality type
        console.log(address_component.long_name); // here's your town name
        return false; // break the loop
    });
```

Comment: afraid that doesn't work. Not sure how it would as there's no variables/arrays for 'addresses' ?

Comment: sorry, I was on about different google maps api request. Edited.

Comment: no worries! any idea how i could get the locality though? I just get undefined in my attempts ;-/ If item.formatted_address works am i wrong in thinking this should too - item.address_components.locality ?

Comment: no, because formatted_address is a string but address_components is an array. I'll add the code on how to look through it.

Comment: first line might be `var arrAddress = item.address_components;` in your case. And your code doesn't work because address_components is an array.

Comment: Works like a charme. Using '.short_name' I finally receive the Cityname without trailing ', Country'. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had to create a program that would fill in the latitude, longitude, city, county, and state fields in a user form when the user clicks on a location on the map. The page can be found at http://krcproject.groups.et.byu.net and is a user form to allow the public to contribute to a database. I don't claim to be an expert, but it works great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() 
  {
    //set initial settings for the map here
    var mapOptions = 
    {
      //set center of map as center for the contiguous US
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.828, -98.5795),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    //load the map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    //This runs when the user clicks on the map
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event)
    {
      //initialize geocoder
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

      //load coordinates into the user form
      main_form.latitude.value = event.latLng.lat();
      main_form.longitude.value = event.latLng.lng();

      //prepare latitude and longitude
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());

      //get address info such as city and state from lat and long
      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
      {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
          //break down the three dimensional array into simpler arrays
          for (i = 0 ; i < results.length ; ++i)
          {
            var super_var1 = results[i].address_components;
            for (j = 0 ; j < super_var1.length ; ++j)
            {
              var super_var2 = super_var1[j].types;
              for (k = 0 ; k < super_var2.length ; ++k)
              {
                //find city
                if (super_var2[k] == "locality")
                {
                  //put the city name in the form
                  main_form.city.value = super_var1[j].long_name;
                }
                //find county
                if (super_var2[k] == "administrative_area_level_2")
                {
                  //put the county name in the form
                  main_form.county.value = super_var1[j].long_name;
                }
                //find State
                if (super_var2[k] == "administrative_area_level_1")
                {
                  //put the state abbreviation in the form
                  main_form.state.value = super_var1[j].short_name;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I love this, thank you, the only thing I would suggest is maybe a check/break for when a component has been found.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you want to get the city and the state / province:

```
var map_center = map.getCenter();
reverseGeocode(map_center);


function reverseGeocode(latlng){
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var level_1;
            var level_2;
            for (var x = 0, length_1 = results.length; x < length_1; x++){
              for (var y = 0, length_2 = results[x].address_components.length; y < length_2; y++){
                  var type = results[x].address_components[y].types[0];
                    if ( type === "administrative_area_level_1") {
                      level_1 = results[x].address_components[y].long_name;
                      if (level_2) break;
                    } else if (type === "locality"){
                      level_2 = results[x].address_components[y].long_name;
                      if (level_1) break;
                    }
                }
            }
            updateAddress(level_2, level_1);
       } 
  });
}

function updateAddress(city, prov){
   // do what you want with the address here
}
```

Don't try to return the results as you will find that they are undefined - a result of an asynchronous service. You must call a function, such as updateAddress();

Comment: you need to break out of every loop, check your console, however the code works great so many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I created this function to get the main info of geocoder results:

```js
const getDataFromGeoCoderResult = (geoCoderResponse) => {
  const geoCoderResponseHead = geoCoderResponse[0];
  const geoCoderData = geoCoderResponseHead.address_components;
  const isEmptyData = !geoCoderResponseHead || !geoCoderData;

  if (isEmptyData) return {};

  return geoCoderData.reduce((acc, { types, long_name: value }) => {
    const type = types[0];

    switch (type) {
      case 'route':
        return { ...acc, route: value };
      case 'locality':
        return { ...acc, locality: value };
      case 'country':
        return { ...acc, country: value };
      case 'postal_code_prefix':
        return { ...acc, postalCodePrefix: value };
      case 'street_number':
        return { ...acc, streetNumber: value };
      default:
        return acc;
    }
  }, {});
};
```

So, you can use it like this:

```js
const geoCoderResponse = await geocodeByAddress(value);
const geoCoderData = getDataFromGeoCoderResult(geoCoderResponse);
```

let's say that you are going search `Santiago Bernabéu Stadium`, so, the result will be:

```js
{
  country: 'Spain',
  locality: 'Madrid',
  route: 'Avenida de Concha Espina',
  streetNumber: '1',
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
const localityObject = body.results[0].address_components.filter((obj) => {
  return obj.types.includes('locality');
})[0];
const city = localityObject.long_name;
```

or in one go:

```
const city = body.results[0].address_components.filter((obj) => {
  return obj.types.includes('locality');
)[0].long_name;
```

I'm doing this in Node, so this is okay. If you need to support IE you need to use a polyfill for [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or find another way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a real pain that google doesn't provide some sort of functionality to get these. Anyhow I think the best way of finding the right object is:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': request.term }, function(results, status){

   response($.map(results, function(item){

      var city = $.grep(item.address_components, function(x){
         return $.inArray('locality', x.types) != -1;
      })[0].short_name;

      alert(city);
   }            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Use Google Geocoder to get Lat/Lon for Address
function codeAddress() {
    // Function geocodes address1 in the Edit Panel and fills in lat and lon
    address = document.getElementById("tbAddress").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            loc[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementById("tbLat").value = loc[0];
            document.getElementById("tbLon").value = loc[1];
            var arrAddress = results[0].address_components;
            for (ac = 0; ac < arrAddress.length; ac++) {
                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "street_number") { document.getElementById("tbUnit").value = arrAddress[ac].long_name }
                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "route") { document.getElementById("tbStreet").value = arrAddress[ac].short_name }
                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "locality") { document.getElementById("tbCity").value = arrAddress[ac].long_name }
                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") { document.getElementById("tbState").value = arrAddress[ac].short_name }
                if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "postal_code") { document.getElementById("tbZip").value = arrAddress[ac].long_name }
            }
            document.getElementById("tbAddress").value = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
        document.getElementById("pResult").innerHTML = 'GeoCode Status:' + status;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns locality if exist. If not - returns `administrative_area_1`

```
city = results[0].address_components.filter(function(addr){
   return (addr.types[0]=='locality')?1:(addr.types[0]=='administrative_area_level_1')?1:0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "street_number") { alert(arrAddress[ac].long_name) } // SOKAK NO
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "route") { alert(arrAddress[ac].short_name); } // CADDE
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "locality") { alert(arrAddress[ac].long_name) } // İL
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") { alert(arrAddress[ac].short_name) } // İL
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "postal_code") { alert(arrAddress[ac].long_name); } // POSTA KODU
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "neighborhood") { alert(arrAddress[ac].long_name); } // Mahalle
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "sublocality") { alert(arrAddress[ac].long_name); } // İlçe
            //if (arrAddress[ac].types[0] == "country") { alert(arrAddress[ac].long_name); } // Ülke
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can use with the lodash js library: (just replace the $scope.x with your own variable name to store the value)

```
    _.findKey(vObj.address_components, function(component) {

            if (component.types[0] == 'street_number') {
                $scope.eventDetail.location.address = component.short_name
            }

            if (component.types[0] == 'route') {
                $scope.eventDetail.location.address = $scope.eventDetail.location.address + " " + component.short_name;
            }

            if (component.types[0] == 'locality') {
                $scope.eventDetail.location.city = component.long_name;
            }

            if (component.types[0] == 'neighborhood') {
                $scope.eventDetail.location.neighborhood = component.long_name;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a lodash function called find which returns the object that the predicate returns true for. As simple as that!

```
let city = find(result, (address) => {
  return typeof find(address.types, (a) => { return a === 'locality'; }) === 'string';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked for me if you want to get the city

```
var city = "";
function getPositionByLatLang(lat, lng) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                //formatted address
                city = results[0].plus_code.compound_code;
                city = city.substr(0, city.indexOf(','));
                city = city.split(' ')[1];

                console.log("the name of city is: "+ city);
            }
        } else {
            // alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As most answers say, the address components change all the time and they vary hugely by country/region. You cannot account just on `locality` because in some addresses and regions that's not available. As an example, check this place ID here in Indonesia: `EjdOeXVoIEt1bmluZyBSb2FkLCBNQVMsIEdpYW55YXIgUmVnZW5jeSwgQmFsaSwgSW5kb25lc2lhIi4qLAoUChIJJzq08aA90i0Rb3AEsy1pPUoSFAoSCcsgYMOTPdItEYAPg8r7CwMF`

A more robust way to find the city is to use the `administrative_area_level` types. If locality is not provided, then take the lower level administrative area (or which one you prefer), like so:

```js
function getAddressComponents(address_components) {

  let address = ''
  let postcode = ''
  let city = ''
  let country = ''
  let country_code = ''
  let postal_code = ''
  let admin_areas: string[] = []

  for (const component of address_components as google.maps.GeocoderAddressComponent[]) {
    const componentType = component.types[0]

    switch (componentType) {
      case 'country':
        country = component.long_name
        country_code = component.short_name
        break
      case 'postal_town':
      case 'locality':
        if (city) {
          city += ', '
        }
        city += component.long_name
        break
      case 'street_number':
      case 'route':
        if (address) {
          address += ', '
        }
        address += component.long_name
        break
      case 'postal_code':
      case 'postal_code_suffix':
        if (postal_code) {
          postal_code += ', '
        }
        postal_code += component.long_name
        break
      default:
        if (componentType.startsWith('administrative_area_level')) {
          admin_areas.push(component.long_name)
        }
    }
  }
  if(!city) {
    city = admin_areas[0]
  }
  return { address, postcode, country, city }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the city without iterate, generally the city is located on the 2nd key of address_components object so the 2nd mean 1:

```
results[0].address_components[1].long_name
```

Comment: This is not true. How you get that?