# How to get the name of the nearest city

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I have some app that sends some information to the internet from time to time let say ones at day. And I can easily send some coordinates (using the gps position) but I do not want that. The android phone is always connected to the internet via wifi or mobile network. But not always enabled the gps. So is it possible to get the location with wifi or mobile network ? I google this thing and I end up with finding location by gps, I do not want to do that.

Can you give me some ideas what can I do this. I have seen web sites that when I open them they know where am I, so I guess it is possible to find the nearest name of the city just by making a internet request and reading the response or maybe use some service . . .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getAddressLine(int)

getLocality looks like it may do what you want?

For websites that know where you are, they either use your source IP and look that up (which isn't very reliable for a lot of things), or they use the javascript geolocation APIs as described here:

http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation

In fact, here's a stack overflow answer on using google API to get to the city name:

[Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/html5-geolocation-easiest-way-to-get-city-name)