# Showing a different web page depending on city

Tags: html, geolocation

I am trying to figure out how I would create a web site that would show a different homepage depending on what city your viewing it in. as in if your in Vancouver it would show mywebsite.com/vancouver etc. I have been looking at HTML5 geo locations and know how to find the location just need to figure out how to use the location to show specific content.
I apologize if this has come up in pervious discussions I couldn't find the answer i was looking for.
thanks

Comment: I see a problem with ip address spoofing and firewall issues. What if the server is the one giving the ip, not a client side machine?

Comment: I found this in the side bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/html5-geolocation-easiest-way-to-get-city-name?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a feat of HTML5 under user acceptance. You can find more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp