# Jquery get current time or offset of a specific country/city name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the current time of a specific country/city on a page. I do not want to use any web-service for this. 
Is there any way to input the Country or City name (like: New York/ San Francisco) and get the current time or just offset value so that the current time can be calculated using it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
```

Because javascript runs on browser

Comment: It'll Just display the current time of users machine. It won't display the time according to a specific country.

Comment: @user199354 Use as below `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/easiest-way-to-get-city-name-using-geolocation`

Comment: Is there any other way than to use a web-service or something?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal How does that link help "get the current time or offset of a specific country/city name"? I'm afraid I don't see the relevancy.