# Javascript, Get city name using geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798005/2068148

The answer in the above link is answered by Michal.

After getting the **results** from **geocoder.geocode** I didn't understand why he checked ***if(results[1])***, he could have checked ***if(results)***...

Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google developers site:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
```

So, i think it should be `results[0]`, see more details at [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat)

See complete example response below for `formatted_address`

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": street_address,
    "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "1600",
      "short_name": "1600",
      "types": street_number
    }, {
      "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "types": route
    }, {
      "long_name": "Mountain View",
      "short_name": "Mountain View",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "San Jose",
      "short_name": "San Jose",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Santa Clara",
      "short_name": "Santa Clara",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "California",
      "short_name": "CA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "94043",
      "short_name": "94043",
      "types": postal_code
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 37.4220323,
        "lng": -122.0845109
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 37.4188847,
          "lng": -122.0876585
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 37.4251799,
          "lng": -122.0813633
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The `if(results[1])` seems to be a mistake/typo because  `geocoder.geocode` writes the results to an array (as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)).

So, the `results` array has one object for each result. This can also be seen by inspecting the `console.log` messages when the code runs-there is a `console.log(results)` in Michal's code.

The `if` statement should be: `if(results.length > 0)` or even `if(results[0])`, but even this would be redundant since if there are no results the previous if statement: `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)` will resolve to false (with status="ZERO_RESULTS").

So you can just remove the `if(results[1])` or replaced it with `if(results.length > 0)` or `if(results[0])`.