# Javascript GeoLocation get users location

Tags: javascript, geolocation

How to get the name (location) of the latitude and longitude a user enters.  Now I have the get geolocation.getCurrentPosition method working which enters my coordinates. But I need it working in the sense of the coordinates the user enters it will retrieve their location as in the name London, Manchester etc

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation

Comment: Basically, you need to choose an api to do it

Comment: NKD. sorry you must have read the question wrong as this is what I have done already.