# Type Error of Geocoder undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-geocoder, angular-google-maps

My `Geocoder` in my Angular project is crashing because it is undefined. I tried this:
[Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geocode' of undefined ' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339494/getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-geocode-of-undefined-error)

But it doesn't work if I initialize it first or assign it. Both do not work.

My code, error in the first line:

```
private geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  @ViewChild('search', { static: false })
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(private maps: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Load places autocomplete
    this.maps.load().then(() => {
      this.setCurrentLocation();

      let autocomplete = new google.place.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // Get the place result
          let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          // Verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          // Set latitude, longitude & zoom
          this.userLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.userLng = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  // Get Current Location Coordinates
  private setCurrentLocation() {
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.userLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 15;
      });
    }
  }

getaddress(latitude, longitude) {
    this.geoCoder.geocode({ "location": { lat: latitude, lng: longitude } }, (results, status) => {
      console.log(results);
      console.log(status);

      if (status === "Ok") {
        if (results[0]) {
          this.zoom = 12;
          this.address = results[0].formatted_address;
        } else {
          window.alert("No results found.");
        }
      } else {
        window.alert("Something went wrong, please try again.");
      }
    });
  }
```

From (scroll down to Add Location/Places Search bar):

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-add-google-maps-in-angular-2-plus-applications-using-angular-google-maps-module-agm-core-easily/

How do you prevent the crash? Thanks!

**EDIT: Fixed:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhbjrx

Comment: Where do you use `geoCoder` which is undefined? Which line?

Comment: The first line, `private geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the correct import statement and using the correct library.

As Geocoder is not defined in `@agm`, but it is defined in `@types/googlemaps` and you need to download it if you do not have it: `npm install --save @types/googlemaps`.

Use this import statement: `import { } from 'googlemaps';` after you made this file, `index.d.ts` in your `src` folder or root one, and declared inside it this:

**index.d.ts**

`declare module "googlemaps";`

And make sure you put brackets with your Geocoder: `Geocoder()`.

This should fix the problem, as it did for me.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhbjrx

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the map loader and then assign the `Geocoder()` in the `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.setCurrentLocation();
      this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  .....
}
```

Make sure to install:

```
npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

**Edit:**

Import properly in module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyCnn-_D68N95BaSpYRYn1E3N_DHGs1vz0Y',
      libraries: ["places"]
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
   ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Same error, but with `maps`, and if I remove the maps to just `google.Geocoder`, it will say the same thing about Geocoder. EDIT: this must be an error of something loading first before Geocoder. It has to be a background loading issue.

Comment: Did you install `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`

Comment: Yes I did install `@types/googlemaps`. I will check again.

Comment: I suggest to create a stackblitz.

Comment: I made a stackblitz.

Comment: I guess the import is issue in your app.module: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-google-maps-autocomplete

Comment: The error still is there, and you do not seem to have the geocoder in your code. I've done what you told me to do in my `app.module`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs since the moment when `Geocoder` is getting initialized, Google Maps API is not yet loaded. In [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/) library `MapsAPILoader` service could be utilized to ensure Google Maps API is loaded and then initialize `Geocoder`:

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
   this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;  
});
```

Here is an example (adapted from the [official Geocoding Service example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)) which demonstrates how to utilize Goolge Maps Geocoding Service with Angular Google Maps

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  center = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
  position= {lat: null, lng: null};
  zoom: number = 8;
  address: string;
  private geoCoder;


  constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
       this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;  
    });
  }


  geocodeAddress(addressInput) {
    const address = addressInput.value;
    this.geoCoder.geocode({'address': address}, (results, status) => {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            this.position = {
              "lat": results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
              "lng": results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            }
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
    });
  }

}
```

And here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwmhee)

Comment: I used your code, but it still gives me the same error. Also, it says that geocode is undefined whenever I would send the data to the geocode method. Maybe there is something wrong with my project config or I messed up with your code somehow... Here is a link to my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhbjrx