# Geolocation code get cities nearby

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, geolocation

How can I build a code to make a Tinder like function?
Let's see:

1- The system gets user geolocalisation info by GPS from user smartphone.
2- This info is latitude and longitude
3- The system gets user radius in KM (example: 50 km radius)
4- Then the system look for cities nearby user inside 50 km radius (the radius is selected by the user)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start by adding the [cordova geolocation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation) to your app? This plugin allows you to get the user's location (longitude and lattitude) as you can see in the examples...
Finding a city next to the user's location might be a trickier, so i would consider using something like the [google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation?rq=1) is a good starting point here, as well as just searching for **reverse geocoding**.