# JSON get geolocation not returning value in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation

I am trying to get geo coordinates and then return them into my HTML. This is the code I have so far, but it is not returning the coordinates onto my page:

```
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $("#cityname").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
  });
}
```

I have an id in my html named 'cityname'. I would also like to convert the coordinates into a city name.

Comment: if you console.log(position) does anything get logged to the console?

Comment: was there popup from browser which asked for allowing to share position with page? you should add fallback code for case when user disagree with this, and blocks position sharing

Comment: if you accidently blocked that popup, you can reset it https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work just fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/sexepm39/

Perhaps your div isn't available in the DOM when this code runs?

Try wrapping it as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            $("#cityname").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        });
    }
});
```

As for getting the city name, this part of your question is already answered: [Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)