# detect current town name using javascript geolocation

Tags: google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Is there a way to get my current AREA/TOWN name by clicking on button, so that people who press on bytton in my website can see their current area/town name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation