# Make JavaScript Google API geocode happen on mouseclick instead of page load

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation

I want this script to be run on a href mouse click instead of on page load.

Here's the original code (as found here: [Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR KEY HERE]"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var geocoder;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
// Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  codeLatLng(lat, lng);
}

function errorFunction() {
  alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({latLng: latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        var arrAddress = results;
        console.log(results);
        $.each(arrAddress, function(i, address_component) {
          if (address_component.types[0] == "locality") {
            console.log("City: " + address_component.address_components[0].long_name);
            itemLocality = address_component.address_components[0].long_name;
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert("No results found");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
  });
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 

</body> 
</html>
```

If I change the `<body onload="initialize()">` to a
`<a href="" onClick="initialize();">Get position</a>` I get a :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geocode' of
>   undefined
>       at codeLatLng 
>       at successFunction

Comment: Probably because of the order things are executed, try to put everything in a function, even variable declaration and then call that function onclick

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
        }
        // Get the latitude and the longitude;
        function successFunction(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            codeLatLng(lat, lng);
        }

        function errorFunction() {
            alert("Geocoder failed");
        }


        function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            geocoder.geocode({
                latLng: latlng
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[1]) {
                        var arrAddress = results;
                        console.log(results);
                        $.each(arrAddress, function(i, address_component) {
                            if (address_component.types[0] == "locality") {
                                console.log("City: " + address_component.address_components[0].long_name);
                                itemLocality = address_component.address_components[0].long_name;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="" onClick="initialize();">Get position</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this loads the script on page load as well. Not only for my onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up loading the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);` if the queryset get_location is set to true. Works. If anyone finds another solution, let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR KEY HERE]"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
      sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
      sParameterName,
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
      sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

      if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
          return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
      }
  }
};

var geocoder;
var getPosition = getUrlParameter('get_position');


if (navigator.geolocation && getPosition == "true") {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
// Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  codeLatLng(lat, lng);
}

function errorFunction() {
  alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({latLng: latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        var arrAddress = results;
        console.log(results);
        $.each(arrAddress, function(i, address_component) {
          if (address_component.types[0] == "locality") {
            console.log("City: " + address_component.address_components[0].long_name);
            itemLocality = address_component.address_components[0].long_name;
          }
        });
      } else {
        alert("No results found");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
  });
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<a href="/?get_position=true">Get position</a>

</body> 
</html>
```