# How can I alert the below JSON code using jquery?

Tags: javascript, json, google-api

I have this json. I am using Reverse Geocoding API from Google. I hit the get request in given url and this is the Response I am getting.

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "Goth Haji Umed Ali Gabole-Konker Road",
                "short_name": "Goth Haji Umed Ali Gabole-Konker Rd",
                "types": [
                    "route"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Haji Umaid Ali Goth",
                "short_name": "Haji Umaid Ali Goth",
                "types": [
                    "political",
                    "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Gadap",
                "short_name": "Gadap",
                "types": [
                    "political",
                    "sublocality",
                    "sublocality_level_1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Karachi",
                "short_name": "Karachi",
                "types": [
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
                ],    "status": "OK"}
```

And this is my code

```
function successFunction(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=AIzaSyBcV_CkYu5VvJb1ZZF8GWCAmyzhedGpYzk";
        jQuery.get(url, function (result)
        {
            console.log(result);
        }
        );
    }
```

JSON is in my console
.
I want to alert city name "Karachi". How can I get this?

Comment: duplicate [Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)

Comment: `alert(result.results[0].address_components[3].long_name);`

Comment: You have your results in the `result` variable. Simply access what you need from this variable. Example in the above comment.

Comment: I added answer, hope it will work as per the requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "results": [{
  "address_components": [{
    "long_name": "Goth Haji Umed Ali Gabole-Konker Road",
    "short_name": "Goth Haji Umed Ali Gabole-Konker Rd",
    "types": [
     "route"
    ]
   },
   {
    "long_name": "Haji Umaid Ali Goth",
    "short_name": "Haji Umaid Ali Goth",
    "types": [
     "political",
     "sublocality",
     "sublocality_level_2"
    ]
   },
   {
    "long_name": "Gadap",
    "short_name": "Gadap",
    "types": [
     "political",
     "sublocality",
     "sublocality_level_1"
    ]
   },
   {
    "long_name": "Karachi",
    "short_name": "Karachi",
    "types": [
     "locality",
     "political"
    ]
   }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
 }]
};

var res = jsonObj.results[0].address_components.filter(obj => obj.long_name == 'Karachi');

console.log(res[0].long_name);
```