# Getting city from lat lon, reverse geocoding to insert in form

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Looking to get just the "city" return value from reverse geocoding in the Google Maps API to insert via a variable into a form. I've looked at the documentation but it doesn't appear to offer a means or example of just getting this value (or any specific value) from this that can then be inserted into a form field in this manner.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359995/get-city-from-geocoder-results

Comment: I'm not looking for an array; just a variable containing the city info I can automatically insert into a form. I already have the map displayed and don't need a marker or other info.

Comment: You're missing the point.  There is no built-in variable.  However, you can parse the response from the geocoding service and only grab what you need: in this case the city.  Once you parse the response, get the city, then you can use JS to set the form field value accordingly.