# Google API Address Components

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am attempting to obtain the address components using the Google Maps API however am unable to properly parse results.  My code is as follows:

```
    // Ajax Call
$.ajax({
    url: 'queryPage.php?',
    data: 'varObtainGoogleAddress=y&' +
          'varAPILink=' + encodeURIComponent(varAPILink),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {   
        // Formatted Address
        varFormattedAddress = data.result['formatted_address'];  // Works!
    }
});
```

What I would like is the city, state and postal code items.  Any help in this regard is appreciated. I am a self taught amateur web developer. :)

Comment: Can you post an example result/response?

Comment: The code above will produce the "formatted address" results however I want to display the various "address_components" ones

Comment: What are you querying exactly and what part of the Google Maps API are you using? Are you reverse geocoding? Maybe there's a way to modify the resulting data, it's not very clear what you are doing. Parsing addresses in itself can be quite challenging.

Comment: Looking for something like this: varStreetAddress = data.result['address_components'].['types'].street_address.long;

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function.

```
/**
*   geocodeResponse is an object full of address data.  
*   This function will "fish" for the right value
*   
*   example: type = 'postal_code' => 
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[5].types[1] = 'postal_code'
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[5].long_name = '1000'
* 
*   type = 'route' => 
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[1].types[1] = 'route'
*   geocodeResponse.address_components[1].long_name = 'Wetstraat'
*/
function addresComponent(type, geocodeResponse, shortName) {
  for(var i=0; i < geocodeResponse.address_components.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < geocodeResponse.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
      if (geocodeResponse.address_components[i].types[j] == type) {
        if (shortName) {
          return geocodeResponse.address_components[i].short_name;
        }
        else {
          return geocodeResponse.address_components[i].long_name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

example of how to use:

```
...
myGeocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[1]) {
    var country = addresComponent('country', results[1], true);
    var postal_code = addresComponent('postal_code', results[1], true);
  }
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you are doing is a [reverse geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse?hl=de).

The object returned looks something like this (from the example):

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "Grand St/Bedford Av",
      "short_name": "Grand St/Bedford Av",
      "types": [
        "bus_station",
        "transit_station",
        "establishment"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Williamsburg",
      "short_name": "Williamsburg",
      "types": [
        "neighborhood",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Brooklyn",
      "short_name": "Brooklyn",
      "types": [
        "sublocality_level_1",
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
...
```

There is no direct way to access a result's street, house number etc. because each part of the address can be several types at the same time. You would have to iterate over the `address_components` and filter according to what you need.

Here's another Stackoverflow thread covering this topic: [get city from geocoder results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359995/get-city-from-geocoder-results)

Answer (score 0):

a little late but this is that i have

calle === street

nro === street_number

```
extraerCalle(resultado: IResult): string | undefined {
    const route = resultado.address_components.find(ac => !!ac.types.find(type => type === 'route'));
    return route && route.long_name;
  }

  extraerNro(resultado: IResult): string | undefined {
    const streetNumber = resultado.address_components.find(ac => !!ac.types.find(type => type === 'street_number'));
    return streetNumber && streetNumber.long_name;
  }

  extraerCalleNro(resultado: IResult): string {
    const calle = this.extraerCalle(resultado);
    const nro = this.extraerNro(resultado);
    return (calle || '') + (calle && nro ? ` ${nro}` : '');
  }
```