# Google geocode with address returns one result

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

Geocoder with an existing address as a parameter returns only the street_address as a result. Why? The address is valid. It has been tested at https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/

My call:

```
   checkAddress(street, strNo, post_code, area, function (results) {
        if (results) { 
     $.each(results, function (i, address) {
    if (address.types[0] == "street_address") {
        itemStreetNo = address.address_components[0].long_name;
        itemStreet = address.address_components[1].long_name;
    }

    if (address.types[0] == "route") {
        itemStreet = address.address_components[0].long_name;
    }

    if (address.types[0] == "postal_code") {
        itemPostalCode = address.address_components[0].long_name;
    }

    if (address.types[0] == "country") {
        itemCountry = address.address_components[0].long_name;
    }

    if (address.types[0] == "locality") {
        itemRegion = address.address_components[0].long_name;
    }
  }
 });
```

My function is:

```
function checkAddress(address, number, zipcode, area, callback) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

    var addr = address + ' ' + number + ' ' + zipcode + ' ' + area;

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addr }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                callback(results);
            }
            else {
                callback(null);
            }
        }
        else {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only search in 1 component (`address.address_components[0]`), so you only get 1 result.

`address.address_components[0]` contains a component, for example "route". Then `address.address_components[1]` contains another component, for example "locality", then `address.address_components[2]` ... As far as I remember the order of the components is random.

So what you need, is to iterate.  For every component you check the type, that lets you know where the value is supposed to go.

I wrote a function for a different Stack Overflow question that does this iteration, that goes "fishing" for whatever component.

See if it works for you; let me know.

[Google API Address Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203977/google-api-address-components/27226620#27226620)

Comment: Thanks for your code. That is what I need to get all the information.